# Can I dispose a Threading.Timer in its callback?

Tags: .net, callback, timer, dispose

I'm using `Threading.Timer`, like:

```
new Timer(new TimerCallback(y=>
{
    try
    {
        Save(Read(DateTime.Now));
        // here i want to dispose this timer
    }
    catch
    {                          
    }
}),null,100000,10000);
```

How can I dispose this timer inside of a callback. or workaround?
Update: Let me explain the situation. I want to try to call the method "Save", while it throws an exception. If it works, I need to stop the timer.

Comment: Have you tried assigning it to a variable and then accessing the variable?

Comment: Why can't you simply wrap the `Timer` in a `using` statement?

Comment: @Cody because the timer may get disposed earlier than intended.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
Timer timer = null;
timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(y =>
{    
    try    
    {
        Save(Read(DateTime.Now));        
        // here i want to dispose this timer
        timer.Dispose();    
    }    
    catch    
    {    
    }
}));
timer.Change(10000, 10000);
```

---

**EDIT:**

I changed the above code slightly according to Chuu's suggestion.  Note that if the TimerCallback is called simultanuously by different timer events, `Timer.Dispose` may end up being called several times.  Luckily the `Timer` does not care if it is being disposed of several times.

Comment: Wow, here I am trying to make this question complicated. The obvious solution is indeed a `Dispose` statement. I assumed this was already excluded as "not an option" for whatever reason.

Comment: I guess it was too obvious :-)

Comment: My loss, your gain. I often try to make things too complicated. +1 for the correct, yet simple, solution.

Comment: I don't think this is 100% thread safe, the following (ridiculously unlikely) series of events could theoretically happen: 1. Timer created.  2.  <context switch> 3.  Callback fire on Threadpool 4.  <context switch>  5.  Assignment occurs.  The thread-safe way would probably be to create the timer with infinite timeouts to force the assignment before the threadpool callback, then use Change() to set the recurring properties.

Comment: @Chuu: Good point. I think you are right.  I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JakobChristensen Resharper gives the following warning "Access to modified closure"? Safe to ignore the warning in this case?

Comment: @user2383728 Resharper is probably complaining that `timer` is being modified outside of the delegate after we created a closure around `timer`. You can ignore the warning in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better way to do this. When you use the constructor with only one param (TimerCallback), the state passed to the callback will be the timer itself.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(o =>
{
     ((Timer)o).Dispose();
     //Your code here     
});

//Start the timer
timer.Change(100000,10000);
```

Here is an example from the msdn docs :

```
public void StartTimer(int dueTime)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(TimerProc));
    t.Change(dueTime, 0);
}

private void TimerProc(object state)
{
    // The state object is the Timer object.
    Timer t = (Timer) state;
    t.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("The timer callback executes.");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to keep the reference of the timer in a variable -

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        _timer =  new Timer(new TimerCallback(y=>{
                            try
                            {
                                Save(Read(DateTime.Now));
                                _timer.Dispose();
                            }
                            catch { 

                            }
                        }),null,100000,10000);
    }



}
```

Note: This is untested code. Please check if it works and update.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store a reference to the timer somewhere and pass that in as state to the timer object itself. Try creating a class something like this:

```
public class TimerContainer
{
  public Timer Timer { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it in your method like so:

```
Action<object> tcb = state =>
{
  var container = (TimerConatiner)state;
  try
  {
    Save(Read(DateTime.Now));
    container.Timer.Dispose();
  }
  catch
  {
    // whatever...
  }
};

var container = new TimerContainer();
container.Timer = new Timer(tcb, container, 100000, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care if you use multithreading or multitasking! if so, here you're the code and a solucion for a CancelAfter method extensor (.net 4.0):

```
       private static object syncObj = new object();

       public static void CancelAfter(this CancellationTokenSource source, int timeoutMilliseconds, Action code = null)
    {
        if (timeoutMilliseconds == 0) return; // No timeout

        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
        if (timeoutMilliseconds < -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeout");
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer(delegate(object self)
        {
            lock (syncObj)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (null != code)
                        code.Invoke();
                    source.Cancel();

                    ((IDisposable)self).Dispose();
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                }                   
            }
        });
        timer.Change(timeoutMilliseconds, -1);
    }
}
```

Regards,
Juanlu, ElGuerre