# Await async TaskEx

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, async-await

What is `TaskEx`? In http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/c/1514-async-await-and-the-ui-problem.html?start=1 or [await TaskEx.Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750600/await-taskex-delay) or [Await async clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711548/await-async-clarification). I use

```
Task DoWork()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 30);
        }
    });
}
```

Examples use this

```
Task DoWork()
{
   return TaskEx.Run(() =>
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(500);
     }
   }
 });
```

I call it like `await DoWork();`
If you use just `Task`, `await` returns nothing and there is no response. If I use `TaskEx` it says it doesn't exist in context.
Should `TaskEx` be a class or something with some sort of function?
Fists one Works it's my mistake.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`TaskEx` was just an extra class which initially shipped with the CTPs of the async/await extensions for C# 5 before .NET 4.5 shipped... and is now part of the [Async Targeting Pack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/p/asynctargetingpackkb/) (aka the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async)) in case you want to use async/await but are targeting .NET 4.0 (which doesn't have some of the code required for it).

If you're using .NET 4.5 or later, just use `Task.Run`, which does the same thing. (You won't be using the targeting pack, so you won't have `TaskEx`.) The async targeting pack can't add a static method to the existing `Task` class, hence the need for `TaskEx` existing at all.

Comment: But my await DoWork(); don't return anything.

Comment: @VladimirLaktionov: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a pause when I call await DoWork(); , then it goes Task DoWork()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 30);
        }
    });
}
|| for a pause, should the pause be doing Task DoWork() or When it goes back to Await DoWork; ?

Comment: @VladimirLaktionov: If you're mostly asking about that, it's very unclear from your question - which has `TaskEx` in the title. It sounds like you've got two separate questions here: 1) What's `TaskEx` and why can't my compiler find it? 2) Why doesn't `Task.Run` behave as I expect it to. Those should be in different posts.

Comment: I apologize it's a weird kind of pause, I put it inside the Loop and it doesn't Cycle again. Mean it does wait. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

"TaskEx is a class that exists only in the CTP, since there was no way to add extra methods to the existing Task class in the Framework (as the CTP is implemented using a separate assembly).

It will not exist in the final, RTM version of the framework.  The methods defined on TaskEx will be migrated to Task."

Source:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74c5ba79-76cc-4f73-a3fa-35616525ab80/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-taskex-?forum=async

CTP was a community preview version of the .NET compiler platform.

Comment: It doesn't only exist in the CTP. It also exists in the async targeting pack.

Comment: I only went by what was stated and accepted on MSDN. I haven't heard of the async targeting pack, is it a part of the .NET library?

Comment: Follow the links in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved with the `System.Threading.Timer`. As [written in the API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Timer__ctor_System_Threading_TimerCallback_System_Object_System_Int32_System_Int32_):

> If `period` is zero (0) or Timeout.Infinite and `dueTime` is not Timeout.Infinite, `callback` is invoked once […]

Ergo, a single-shot timer can be created as, for instance,

```
Timer oneShotTimer = new Timer((object stateInfo) => {
  // your callback code here
}, null, yourOneShotTimePeriodHere, Timeout.Infinite);
```

There’s also a trick in the API to dispose of the timer from within its callback method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26410217/3517056